# What is the "cut-and-paste" proof technique?

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

I've seen references to *cut-and-paste* proofs in certain texts on algorithms analysis and design. It is often mentioned within the context of Dynamic Programming when proving *optimal substructure* for an optimization problem (See Chapter 15.3 CLRS). It also shows up on graphs manipulation.

What is the main idea of such proofs? How do I go about using them to prove the correctness of an algorithm or the convenience of a particular approach?

Comment: I dont understand why this is not a real question . I've encountered cut and paste proofs multiple places in algorithm texts . How this question became "" ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered "" ??
@Cameron even gave a good explanation about the essence of such a proof wrt to dynamic programming ..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The term "cut and paste" shows up in algorithms sometimes when doing dynamic programming (and other things too, but that is where I first saw it). The idea is that in order to use dynamic programming, the problem you are trying to solve probably has some kind of underlying redundancy. You use a table or similar technique to avoid solving the same optimization problems over and over again. Of course, before you start trying to use dynamic programming, it would be nice to prove that the problem has this redundancy in it, otherwise you won't gain anything by using a table. This is often called the "optimal subproblem" property (e.g., in CLRS).

The "cut and paste" technique is a way to prove that a problem has this property. In particular, you want to show that when you come up with an optimal solution to a problem, you have necessarily used optimal solutions to the constituent subproblems. The proof is by contradiction. Suppose you came up with an optimal solution to a problem by using suboptimal solutions to subproblems. Then, if you were to replace ("cut") those suboptimal subproblem solutions with optimal subproblem solutions (by "pasting" them in), you would improve your optimal solution. But, since your solution was optimal by assumption, you have a contradiction. There are some other steps involved in such a proof, but that is the "cut and paste" part.

Answer (score 3):

'cut-and-paste' technique can be used in proving both correctness of greedy algorithm (both optimal structure and greedy-choice property' and dynamic programming algorithm correctness.

## Greedy Correctness

This lecture notes [Correctness of MST](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/resources/lecture-16-greedy-algorithms-minimum-spanning-trees/) from MIT 2005 undergrad algorithm class exhibits 'cut-and-paste' technique to prove both optimal structure and greedy-choice property.

This lecture notes [Correctness of MST](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-046j-design-and-analysis-of-algorithms-spring-2015/pages/lecture-notes/) from MIT 6.046J / 18.410J spring 2015 use 'cut-and-paste' technique to prove greedy-choice property

## Dynamic Programming Correctness

A more authentic explanation for 'cut-and-paste' was introduced in CLRS (3rd edtion) Chapter 15.3 Element of dynamic programming at page 379

"4. You show that the solutions to the subproblems used within the optimal solution to the problem must themselves be optimal by using a “cut-and-paste”
technique, You do so by supposing that each of the subproblem solutions is not optimal and then deriving a contradiction. In particular, by “cutting out” the nonoptimal subproblem solution and “pasting in” the optimal one, you show that you can get a better solution to the original problem, thus contradicting your supposition that you already had an optimal solution. If there is more than one subproblem, they are typically so similar that the cut-and-paste argument for one can be modified for the others with little effort."

Answer (score 2):

Cut-and-Paste is a way used in proofing graph theory concepts, Idea is this: Assume you have solution for Problem A, you want to say some edge/node, should be available in solution. You will assume you have solution without specified edge/node, you try to reconstruct a solution by cutting an edge/node and pasting specified edge/node and say new solution benefit is at least as same as previous solution.

One of a most important samples is proving MST attributes (proving that greedy choice is good enough). see [presentation on MST from CLRS book](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-twelve/).

Answer (score 2):

Proof by contradiction

P is assumed to be false, that is !P is true.

It is shown that !P implies two mutually contradictory assertions, Q and !Q.

Since Q and !Q cannot both be true, the assumption that P is false must be wrong, and P must be true.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a new proof technique per se.  It is just a fun way to articulate a proof by contradiction.

An example of cut-and-paste:

Suppose you are solving the shortest path problem in graphs with vertices x_1, x_2... x_n.  Suppose you find a shortest path from x_1 to x_n and it goes through x_i and x_j (in that order).  Then, clearly, the sub path from x_i to x_j must be a shortest path between x_i and x_j as well.  Why?  Because Math.

Proof using Cut and Paste:
Suppose there exists a strictly shorter path from x_i to x_j.  "Cut" that path, and "Paste" into the overall path from x_1 to x_n.  Then, you will have another path from x_1 to x_n that is (strictly) shorter than the previously known path, and contradicts the "shortest" nature of that path.

Plain Old Proof by Contradiction:
Suppose P: The presented path from x_1 to x_n is a shortest path.
Q: The subpath from x_i to x_j is a shortest path.
The, Not Q => not P (using the argument presented above.
Hence, P => Q.

So, "Cut" and "Paste" makes it a bit more visual and easy to explain.