# Is finding a minimum integer within an array of integers be considered having an optimal substructure?

Tags: optimization, integer, minimum

The problem I'm facing is that I have been told that it is not so. But I don't understand why, because when we talk about optimal substructure we try to find the optimal solution of a bigger problem using the one solution of a sub problem. Can't we consider fining the minimum among i integers having its optimal solution being derived from the minimum among {a[i]} and min{a[1],.....,a[i-1]} which are solutions to again its sub problems? Actually we can even considers the sub problems in divide and conquer fashion.

Comment: I understand you're asking a question about dynamic programming. But I don't understand what you're trying to ask. If you're asking how dynamic programming works then I'd suggest looking at the cut n paste proof: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553162/what-is-a-cut-and-paste-proof

Comment: I am just asking whether "finding the least integer" has an optimal substructure property. If not, why?